# How to merge two xml nodes together in shell script?

Tags: linux, xml, bash, shell, unix

I have a xml like this below. Need to two  tags data together

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes?>
<add>
<docs>
<doc> 
<field name="sku.active_flag">true</field> 
<field name="sku.available_in_postpay">false</field> 
<field name="sku.available_in_prepay">false</field> 
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="sku_dpp_all_eligibleflow_AAL">TRADEIN_PROMO</field>
<field name="sku_dpp_all_eligibleflow_EUP">TRADEIN_PROMO</field>
<field name="sku_dpp_all_eligibleflow_NSE">TRADEIN_PROMO</field>
</doc>
</docs>
</add>
```

I tried `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/add/docs/doc" /tmp/xml_data`, but it does not work.

Expected output:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes?>
<add>
<docs>
<doc> 
<field name="sku.active_flag">true</field> 
<field name="sku.available_in_postpay">false</field> 
<field name="sku.available_in_prepay">false</field>
<field name="sku_dpp_all_eligibleflow_AAL">TRADEIN_PROMO</field>
<field name="sku_dpp_all_eligibleflow_EUP">TRADEIN_PROMO</field>
<field name="sku_dpp_all_eligibleflow_NSE">TRADEIN_PROMO</field>
</doc>
</docs>
</add>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I can do with powershell script

Comment: It can be easily solved with Perl!

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple XSLT transformation. Using XSLT 3.0

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy">
  <xsl:template match="docs">
    <docs><doc><xsl:copy-of select="doc/field"/></doc></docs>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Also easy in earlier versions of XSLT, but a bit more verbose.

Comment: Are there widely available XSLT 3.0 implementations in command-line-accessible form? (IIRC, xsltproc implements an older revision).

Comment: The most commonly used XSLT 3.0 implementation is probably my company's product Saxon, which is readily invoked from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I would move all the children of the second (and later) `doc` nodes to the first and then delete the empty nodes:

```
xml ed -m "//doc[position()>1]//*" "//doc[1]" -d  '//doc[position()>1]' file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy with Perl, my code uses a regular expression to match the specific pattern `<\/doc>\n\n` (linebreaks included) and replaces it with an empty string!

```
perl -i -p0e 's/(<\/doc>\n<doc>)\n//g' input.xml
```

Comment: Please try it on the test file first and then on the original file!